# Error When Uploading Pandas Dataframe to Azure SQL Server Database With Active Directory Interactive/2MFA Using Pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

Hi wonderful StackOverflow community!

I am in need of your divine help, as I am unable to find an answer elsewhere.

When using Python (version 3.10.2 64-bit), I try to upload a Pandas Dataframe 'hr_personaldata' to an Azure SQL Server Database 'hr-data' on the SQL Server 'test-sql-azure-01.database.windows.net'.

I am able to use *pyodbc* package with the **ActiveDirectoryInteractive** authentication method to create the connection after entering my password and approving the connection on my Authenticator app. The code to get this connection going is stated below and works to establish the connection:

```
# Create a connection to the database
import pyodbc
server = 'test-sql-azure-01.database.windows.net'
database = 'hr-data'
username ='test-user@company.com'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';SERVER='+server+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication
                      )
```

When trying to read data from the database, this works fine. However, when sending data to the database, an error occurs. I am using the following code to send the data to the database, where 'hr_personaldata' is of the type 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' and filled with personal HR data:

```
hr_personaldata.to_sql('HR_PersonalData', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

The full error which is returned by this statement is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2017, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2016 try:
-> 2017     cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   2018     return cur

OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2021, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2020 try:
-> 2021     self.con.rollback()
   2022 except Exception as inner_exc:  # pragma: no cover

OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (-2147467259) (SQLEndTran)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\r.vdaa\Documents\Scripts HR-Data Processing\main.py in <module>
----> 108 hr_personaldata.to_sql('HR_PersonalData', conn, if_exists='replace')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2963, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2806 """
   2807 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
   2808 
   (...)
   2959 [(1,), (None,), (2,)]
   2960 """  # noqa:E501
   2961 from pandas.io import sql
-> 2963 return sql.to_sql(
   2964     self,
   2965     name,
   2966     con,
   2967     schema=schema,
   2968     if_exists=if_exists,
   2969     index=index,
   2970     index_label=index_label,
   2971     chunksize=chunksize,
   2972     dtype=dtype,
   2973     method=method,
   2974 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:697, in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
    692 elif not isinstance(frame, DataFrame):
    693     raise NotImplementedError(
    694         "'frame' argument should be either a Series or a DataFrame"
    695     )
--> 697 return pandas_sql.to_sql(
    698     frame,
    699     name,
    700     if_exists=if_exists,
    701     index=index,
    702     index_label=index_label,
    703     schema=schema,
    704     chunksize=chunksize,
    705     dtype=dtype,
    706     method=method,
    707     engine=engine,
    708     **engine_kwargs,
    709 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2186, in SQLiteDatabase.to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, **kwargs)
   2175             raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")
   2177 table = SQLiteTable(
   2178     name,
   2179     self,
   (...)
   2184     dtype=dtype,
   2185 )
-> 2186 table.create()
   2187 return table.insert(chunksize, method)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:828, in SQLTable.create(self)
    827 def create(self):
--> 828     if self.exists():
    829         if self.if_exists == "fail":
    830             raise ValueError(f"Table '{self.name}' already exists.")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:812, in SQLTable.exists(self)
    811 def exists(self):
--> 812     return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2194, in SQLiteDatabase.has_table(self, name, schema)
   2191 wld = "?"
   2192 query = f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name={wld};"
-> 2194 return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2026, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2022 except Exception as inner_exc:  # pragma: no cover
   2023     ex = DatabaseError(
   2024         f"Execution failed on sql: {args[0]}\n{exc}\nunable to rollback"
   2025     )
-> 2026     raise ex from inner_exc
   2028 ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")
   2029 raise ex from exc

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054)')
unable to rollback
```

The following warning was also given:

```
C:\Users\r.vdaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:758: UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
  warnings.warn(
```

Is anyone able to help me out here, as I am stuck on this project for a customer and can't seem to find an answer.

Thanks a lot, lot of love to the StackOverflow community, and keep up the good work!!

Greeting,

Ricardo